# Position: fixed does not work in internet explorer

Tags: css, position, fixed

I just don't get it.

I got three simple rows for a website. Just those three:

```
<div style='height: 3000px; border: 10px dotted blue;'>
<div style='position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 100px; border: 2px dashed red; height: 100px; width: 100px;'></div>
</div>
```

Now can somebody please explain me, why the fixed inner div just does not stay where it is in Internet explorer? Works perfectly in Firefox...

Thank you for help!

Comment: Did you try it with a doctype? IE switches to quirksmode if it's missing.

Comment: Works perfectly in IE7/8/9 with me. Maybe your IE is broken (not that it is anyway :)

Comment: @Martin, you were right. I just added the Doctype and it worked. If you write an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general: If something's fishy in the way the Internet Explorer displays a web page, it might just be that it's in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

A lot of times this happens because the [DTD (=doctype declaration)](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype) was forgotten.

Try adding a DTD as well as a proper html page structure and it will probably fix your problem.

Although it's a Microsoft product, *the Internet Explorer actually respects and follows standards if you do so as well.*

Comment: the Internet Explorer actually respects and follows standards if you do so as well. haha, yeah right.